# luarocks package installer could not find header file for CRYPTO (crypto.h)

Tags: lua, openssl, luarocks, lapis

I am trying to install lapis through `luarocks`. When I run `luarocks install lapis`, the terminal returns this error:

```
Warning: falling back to wget - install luasec to get native HTTPS support
Installing https://luarocks.org/lapis-1.9.0-1.src.rock
Missing dependencies for lapis 1.9.0-1:
   luaossl (not installed)
   pgmoon (not installed)

lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on lua (5.4-1 provided by VM)
lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on ansicolors (1.0.2-3 installed)
lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on date (2.2-2 installed)
lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on etlua (1.3.0-1 installed)
lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on loadkit (1.1.0-1 installed)
lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on lpeg (1.0.2-1 installed)
lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on lua-cjson (2.1.0-1 installed)
lapis 1.9.0-1 depends on luaossl (not installed)
Installing https://luarocks.org/luaossl-20220711-0.src.rock

Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/luaossl-20220711-0.src.rock - Could not find header file for CRYPTO
  No file openssl/crypto.h in /usr/local/include
  No file openssl/crypto.h in /usr/include
  No file openssl/crypto.h in /include
  No file openssl/crypto.h in /usr/local/opt/include
You may have to install CRYPTO in your system and/or pass CRYPTO_DIR or CRYPTO_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install luaossl CRYPTO_DIR=/usr/local
```

I have openssl installed (I am on apple silicone). To install openssl, I just cloned the [git repo](https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git) and then ran:

`./Configure`

`make`

`make test`

As stipulated in the `INSTALL.MD` file. I think this is an issue a few others have had but there are no answers on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only followed the instructions in the "Building OpenSSL" section of `INSTALL.MD`. You skipped the ones in the "Installing OpenSSL" section, so it's not actually installed. Follow them too and then try again.